# Prime Number Simple Test

Tags: javascript

the following code always seems to return true whatever value of n I plug in and I can't see why. If n = 8, then arr2 should contain the value of i for 2, 4 and 8?
Can someone please explain? Thank you very much.

```
var primetest = function(n){
    var divisor  = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    for (var i = 0; i < divisor.length; i++) {
            var arr2 = [];
            if(n%divisor[i] == 0) {arr2.push(i);}
                    if(arr2.length > 1) {prime = false;}
                    else {prime = true;}
                    return prime;
            };
    };
```

Comment: Your return statement is within the loop, so the whole function ends when this statement is reach in the first iteration of it.

Comment: place the If(arr2.length>1) check after the for loop

Comment: ...and you reset the arr2 variable on each loop iteration - move that var statement outside the loop.

Comment: Please, remove that `divisor` array and replace every `divisor[i]` by simply `(i+2)`! (or even simpler make the loop `for (var i=2; i<21; i++)`)

Comment: @Bergi - surely it would be (i+2) in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of problems in your original code:

- You are doing only one iteration
- You declare the array holding divisions inside the loop, causing it to always have maximum 1 item.

Quick fix of the above would be:

```
var primetest = function(n){
    var divisor  = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var arr2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < divisor.length; i++) {
        if(n%divisor[i] == 0) {
            arr2.push(i);
        }
    }
    return arr2.length <=1;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/N9T3D/).

Optimized code that does not iterate through the whole list of divisors if not reuired (guess that's what you were trying to achieve) is:

```
var primetest = function(n){
    var divisor  = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var arr2 = [];    
    for (var i = 0; i < divisor.length; i++) {
        if(n % divisor[i] === 0) {
            arr2.push(i);
            if (arr2.length > 1)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9T3D/1/).

Comment: You should also mention that you moved the initialization of arr2 to outside the loop to prevent it from being cleared on each iteration.

Comment: @roviuser I did: "and declare the array holding divisions outside the loop as well" :)

Comment: This solution will iterate through the entire divisor array (19 times) regardless of whether the number is known to be prime before getting to the end of the array. For example suppose n is 4.  After 3 loops in the array you'll know that n is not prime. As soon as arr2.length is > 1, you can return false.

Comment: @Fotiman fair enough, I was just fixing what was broken. Will add optimized version as well.

Comment: You could make this even more efficient if you wanted. First I thought "there's no need to do the arr2.push(i) and THEN check the length... as in, you could do

    if(n % divisor[i] === 0) {
        if (arr2.length > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        arr2.push(i);
    }

But that got me thinking... there's really no need to have an arr2. Instead, all that's needed is a boolean to store whether a match has already been made.  But again... might be overkill to worry about optimizing to such a degree. :)

Comment: @Fotiman yeah, I think the current code is efficient enough and still very readable, and allow easy debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:
Don't declare you array inside the loop, because it will reset in every loop.
And move your return outside of the loop because your function will return at first loop, wich always true for odd numbers(n%2 = 0 for even numbers).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XzYF8/)

```
function primetest(n){
var divisor  = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
var arr2 = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < divisor.length; i++) {

      if((n%divisor[i]) === 0) 
          arr2.push(i);
      if(arr2.length > 1)
          prime = false;   
      else prime = true;                   
  };
  return prime;     
}

$(function (){
  var pprime = 7;

  if(primetest(pprime))   
  alert("ok");   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the first 1001 positions into an array of prime numbers.
Usefull code to modify, enjoy!

```
//cum calculam daca un numar este prim
//chiar mai mult - care este al 1001-lea nr prim
function isPrime(num) {
if(num < 2) return false;
for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if(num%i===0)
        return false;
}
return true;
}
var shir=[];
var j=0;
var i=1;
while(j<1001)
{
if(isPrime(i)) 
{shir[j]=i;
j++;i++}
else{i++}
}
console.log(shir);
console.log (shir[0]);
console.log (shir[1000]);
alert("Al 1001-lea numar prim este " + shir[1000]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your condition

```
if(arr2.length > 1) {prime = false;}
```

is checking for `>1` instead of `>0` or `>=1` which is ignoring the prime condition that you specified. Hence your corrected code would be something like this:

```
var primetest = function(n){
    var divisor  = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    for (var i = 0; i < divisor.length; i++) {
            var arr2 = [];
            if(n%divisor[i] == 0) {arr2.push(i);}
                    if(arr2.length > 0) {prime = false;}
                    else {prime = true;}
                    return prime;
            };
    };
if(arr2.length > 1) {prime = false;}
```

There are better ways to check for prime number. Here's the fastest one I could lay my hands on:

```
var primetest = function(n) {
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n%1 || n<2) return false; 
 if (n==leastFactor(n)) return true;
 return false;
}

// leastFactor(n)
// returns the smallest prime that divides n
//     NaN if n is NaN or Infinity
//      0  if n=0
//      1  if n=1, n=-1, or n is not an integer

leastFactor = function(n){
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n)) return NaN;  
 if (n==0) return 0;  
 if (n%1 || n*n<2) return 1;
 if (n%2==0) return 2;  
 if (n%3==0) return 3;  
 if (n%5==0) return 5;  
 var m = Math.sqrt(n);
 for (var i=7;i<=m;i+=30) {
  if (n%i==0)      return i;
  if (n%(i+4)==0)  return i+4;
  if (n%(i+6)==0)  return i+6;
  if (n%(i+10)==0) return i+10;
  if (n%(i+12)==0) return i+12;
  if (n%(i+16)==0) return i+16;
  if (n%(i+22)==0) return i+22;
  if (n%(i+24)==0) return i+24;
 }
 return n;
}
```

Source: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/numberisprime.htm